# Is Read/Write speed dependent upon indexes?

Tags: mysql, database-design, indexing, foreign-keys, unique-constraint

I have a table named `Votes`. Now I have a few FK (foreign key) on some of its columns. Also as you know, I need to create an index on FK-column. If I create an index on a column *(for example `Votes.user_id` on `User.id`)* , will the speed of reads and write be increased, or decreased?

I ask because there are multiple columns that I need to set a FK on:

```
// Votes table
 . post_id on Posts.id
 . user_id on Users.id
 . author_id on Users.id
```

Also I need a unique-index on `(Post_id, user_id)` to detect duplicate votes. Anyway, three separated indexes and one unique index is a normal thing on the Votes table?

Comment: BTW: `author_id` seams to be redundant. I guess it is already stored in `Posts` table.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes `author_id` is already stored in `Posts` table, but I need to send a notification to the author after insert a vote using a trigger.

Comment: You can select `author_id` from `Posts` or use `JOIN Posts` in your `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statement in the trigger. Maybe you ask a new question on that issue because it's OT here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Decide what indexes will speed up the `SELECTs` and `UPDATEs`.  You can't really pick indexes without knowing what you will be searching for.
2. Don't worry about how much (not much) it slows down writes.

[*More on creating indexes*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) will help you decide what indexes are worth having.

Answer (score 2):

Creating indexes speeds up reads, but slows down writes.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys as well as unique indexes grant the integrity of your data.
You should not skip them, unless you have a very good reason.
You'll rarely (or not at all) find such a reason.

Write accesses are slowed down by indexes because the indexes need to be updated too.
But this performance losses are limited.
In contrast, the loss of performance can be enormous if you want to search, sort or join tables without using indexes.
From a certain size of the tables, searching and sorting are very slow and joins practically impossible without appropriate indexes.

So in your case, the set of indexes you defined in the question, is not just "normal", it's the minimum (IMHO). Not unlikely you will need some more, depending on other columns and your queries.